# Number of primes with $-1\pmod 6$ vs. Number of primes with $+1\pmod 6$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Given the following two sets:

- $P^-(n) = \{p \leq n : p \equiv -1\pmod 6\}$
- $P^+(n) = \{p \leq n : p \equiv +1\pmod 6\}$

For example:

- $P^-(40) = \{5,11,17,23,29\}$
- $P^+(40) = \{7,13,19,31,37\}$

Given the following two functions:

- $C^-(n)=|P^-(n)|$
- $C^+(n)=|P^+(n)|$

For example:

- $C^-(40) = 5$
- $C^+(40) = 5$

Is there a known bound of the difference between $C^-(n)$ and $C^+(n)$?

In other words, is there a known maximum value for $|C^-(n)-C^+(n)|$?

---

**Updated Question:**

1. Has it been proved that $\forall k \exists n : k=|C^-(n)-C^+(n)|$?
2. Has any bound been proved for $|C^-(n)-C^+(n)|$ relatively to $n$ (e.g., $\ln \ln n$)?
3. What is the largest known value of $|C^-(n)-C^+(n)|$, and for what value of $n$ does it hold?

Comment: Have you tried to see how this varies for large $n$?

Comment: @user88595: I would need to compute all prime numbers up to this large $n$ then, wouldn't I? That might be a little bit of a problem for a **really** large $n$...

Comment: Of course but you could see a start of a trend if there is any.

Comment: Just saying... Let's say I claim the difference is at most 10^100. Does it seem likely that the difference is less than 10^100 if I examine all the primes up to 10^1,000,000? If you take the heuristics that n = 6k +/- 1 is prime with probability 3 / ln (n), what kind of variation would you expect? You should analyse that heuristics and ask whether the numbers deviate from that heuristics.

Comment: @user88595: Your picture just about looks as if there might be a trend, and that barak might be advised to write a little program that searches for data up to 10^12, for example.

Comment: @gnasher729 : Do you have any idea how much $10^{12}$ is? That's impossible to compute, even in a life time. I estimate it would take 2 million years on my poor laptop. Of course there is space for improvement but still...

Comment: Surely the difference is unbounded, both above and below. Search for "prime number races".

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks; please see updated question. BTW, even if this difference is unbound in theory, I would expect the maximum known value of it to be very small relatively to the largest prime in the known sequence of consecutive primes.

Comment: I would expect you would find the answers to your questions if you would take my search suggestion. But perhaps you don't have access to Google, so: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/PrimeRace.pdf

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks (and LOL on Google). But this term seems to be referring to $4n\pm1$, not to $6n\pm1$.

Comment: You have to read beyond page 1.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/165887/number-of-primes-with-1-pmod-6-vs-number-of-primes-with-1-pmod-6 (as OP should have noted here).